# Input field unable to display text in w3.css

Tags: html, css, w3.css

I'm trying to create a nav with search functionality. When I input text input field, nothing is displayed. Also how do I deactivate the hover effect? ...using w3.css framework. Thanks[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzbFn.png)

```
<div class="w3-top">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-cyan text-color-black w3-large" style="height:         49px; color: black">
 <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
<li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
<li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Dashboard</a>       </li>
 <li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Bookmarks</a></li>
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-small" style="width: 350px; height: 30px; margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 10px" name="first" type="text" placeholder="search names here">
<button class="w3-btn w3-small w3-white w3-border w3-round" style="margin-left: 615px; margin-top: -30px; height: 30px">Search</button>
<!--<" style="width:450px; height:28px; margin-left: 390px; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 70%" name="first" type="text">-->
</div>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why there is an ending `</div>` tag before `</ul>` remove it.

```
<div class="w3-top">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-cyan text-color-black w3-large" style="height:         49px; color: black">
 <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
<li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
<li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Dashboard</a>       </li>
 <li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Bookmarks</a></li>
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-small" style="width: 350px; height: 30px; margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 10px" name="first" type="text" placeholder="search names here">
<button class="w3-btn w3-small w3-white w3-border w3-round" style="margin-left: 615px; margin-top: -30px; height: 30px">Search</button>
<!--<" style="width:450px; height:28px; margin-left: 390px; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 70%" name="first" type="text">-->
</div> <!--please remove this line --> 
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="w3-top">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-cyan text-color-black w3-large" style="height:         49px; color: black">
 <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
<li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
<li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Dashboard</a>       </li>
 <li class="w3-right" style="font-size: 90%"><a href="#">Bookmarks</a></li>
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-small" style="width: 350px; height: 30px; margin-left: 400px; margin-top: 10px" name="first" type="text" placeholder="search names here">
<button class="w3-btn w3-small w3-white w3-border w3-round">Search</button>
<!--<" style="width:450px; height:28px; margin-left: 390px; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 70%" name="first" type="text">-->
</div> <!--please remove this line --> 
 </ul>
 </div>
```

This is because button layer is over input type layer. so you can't see anything typing. you need to remove all inline CSS for the button.

Hello

Log Out
    Dashboard       
     Bookmarks
    
    Search
    -->

Please check this now. it's working in snippet

Comment: Hello... I tried to remove all inline CSS in the buttons but still can't see text in input field.

Comment: please check in snippet